# Тестирование nodejs (express) приложения

Tags: javascript, node.js, юнит-тесты

Хочу спросить ваше мнение, у меня есть 2 сущности:
Роуты

```
import express from 'express';

import * as ProductController from '../controllers/product';
import checkToken from '../middlewares/checkToken';
import getUser from '../middlewares/getUser';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/products', checkToken, getUser, ProductController.create);
router.put('/products', checkToken, getUser, ProductController.update);
router.get('/products/:categoryUrl', ProductController.getProductsByCategoryUrl);
router.get('/products/:categoryUrl/:productUrl', checkToken, getUser, ProductController.getProductByUrl);
router.get('/products', ProductController.getAll);

export default router;
```

И соответсвующие им контроллеры:

```
import Product from '../models/product';
import Category from '../models/category';
import * as PageStatusService from '../services/pageStatusService';
import * as CategoryService from '../services/categoryService';
import urlCheck from '../helpres/check-is-valid-url';

export async function create(req, res, next) {
  const productData = req.body;
  const userId = req.user._id;
  let product;
  let isStatusExist;
  let isCategoryExist;

  productData.user = userId;

  if (!urlCheck(productData.url)) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message: 'Invalid url value'
    });
  }

  try {
    isStatusExist = await PageStatusService.isExistStatus(productData.status);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message
    });
  }

  if (!isStatusExist) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message: 'Invalid status value'
    });
  }

  // TODO: add check for category, product belong to last level category
  // if categories with parent category productData.category is empty

  try {
    isCategoryExist = await CategoryService.isExistCategoryById(productData.category);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message
    });
  }

  if (!isCategoryExist) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message: 'Invalid category value'
    });
  }

  try {
    product = await Product.create(productData);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message
    });
  }

  res.json(product);
}

...
```

Так вот, стоит ли отдельно тетсировать контроллер, или тестировать только роуты, кт по сути тестирую роут мы сразу тестируем и контроллер, что то типо:

```
var should = require('should'); 
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');  
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var winston = require('winston');
var config = require('./config-debug');

  describe('Account', function() {
    it('should return error trying to save duplicate username', function(done) {
      var profile = {
        username: 'vgheri',
        password: 'test',
        firstName: 'Valerio',
        lastName: 'Gheri'
      };
    // once we have specified the info we want to send to the server via POST verb,
    // we need to actually perform the action on the resource, in this case we want to 
    // POST on /api/profiles and we want to send some info
    // We do this using the request object, requiring supertest!
    request(url)
    .post('/api/profiles')
    .send(profile)
    // end handles the response
    .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          // this is should.js syntax, very clear
          res.should.have.status(400);
          done();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно понимать что существует множество видов тестирования, самые актуальные из которых -

- **юнит-тестировани** - в ходе теста проверяются имплементация интерфейсов. Другими словами, проверки подвергаются все публичные методы объекта, модуля, комопнента.
- **интеграционное тестирование** - в ходе тестирования проверяется работа совокупности отдельных частей программы.
- **системное тестирование** - в ходе теста проверяется выполнение работы самой программы.

*Все виды тестирования являются разными слоями абстракции и применяются на разных временных этапах создания программы*.

Поэтому, как Вы сами могли уже заметить, Ваш вопрос заключается в том, можно ли пропустить этап юнит-тестирования и сразу писать интеграционные.

Я бы не советовал, но дело все равно за Вами.